# to get property of other objects into the class methods, into my Gazzet calss

Tags: php

in my Gazzet class i m facing error , i cant understand please explain it,

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in E:\Web\xampp\htdocs\oop\includes\gazett.php on line 71
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in E:\Web\xampp\htdocs\oop\includes\gazett.php on line 72
Notice: Undefined variable: courseName in E:\Web\xampp\htdocs\oop\includes\gazett.php on line 174
Fatal error: Cannot access empty property in E:\Web\xampp\htdocs\oop\includes\gazett.php on line 174

```
class Gazzet{
 private $course, $Regid ;
 public $InstName, $Address;
 public $courseName, $E_Year;
 public $InstName, $Address;
 public $courseName, $E_Year;

 function __construct($Course, $Regid){
     $this->course=$Course;
     $this->Regid=$Regid;
     $this->madersaName(); 
     $this->course_name();
 }

private function madersaName(){
 global $obj_madrsa_name;
 $obj_madrsa_name = Madaris::madaris_by_id($this->Regid);//here i want to try get public property of obj_madrsa_name , but in vein i m error facing
 $this->InstName=$obj_madrsa_name->InstName;// same  above error, line 71
 $this->Address=$obj_madrsa_name->Address; //same  above error, line 72
```

}

```
 private function course_name(){
     global $obj_course;
     $obj_course = Courses::courseName($this->course);
     $this->$courseName = $obj_course->courseName; // same here, above given error face, line 174
     $this->$E_Year = $obj_course->E_Year; // same here, above given error face, line 174
}
```

}

$gazett = new Gazett($Course);

Comment: could you put your other classes here as well and indent it properly?

Answer (score 0):

your construct need to 2 parameters : `__construct($Course, $Regid )` !!!
you give it only one parametere in your instance creation :

```
$gazett = new Gazett($Course);
```

Note: you write : Ga`z`ett , but your class name is : Ga`zz`et !!!
may be ist your problem !!! try to check it !!!

Comment: no it is not working , the problem is same , same error facing ? :(

Answer (score 0):

$gazett = new Gazzet($Course, $Regid);

Use this line
I hope ur problem will be solve 
plz check this...